# GKE- sudo docker ps returns nothing while deployment is running

Tags: kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

i have created a deployment on gke!!

When i run `kubectl get pods` from my local machine, it returns me the existing pods and the deployment is running,
but if i run on worker node via ssh `docker ps`, it doesn't return any container..

i used cos_containered.
I have one node in my cluster and the pod has been scheduled there!

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: you should see the output if you do `docker ps` on "the worker nodes".

Comment: Isn't there only worker nodes and control plane?? the pod is created in the node i checked!!  i will see the output in a while and i'll add screenshots... thank you for your answer!!

Comment: GKE doesn't use docker for the container runtime. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/using-containerd. You'll likely see more major platforms move away from docker in the future now that k8s has official CRI-O support.

Comment: Cloud Shell is a dedicated VM with the Cloud SDK and other tools installed.  You are not actually connecting to any of the GKE worker nodes so running `docker ps` in Cloud Shell won't return anything (unless you use Docker to start containers yourself).

What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @jordanm thank youu, you were right.. Just now i noticed the difference.. Do you know if it is necessary to use cos_containerd(with Containers ) and not cos(with Docker)?

Comment: Use of Docker as the container runtime has been deprecated in k8s so GKE defaults to using cos_containerd.  What exactly are you hoping to see/prove running these commands on nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GKE is moving away from `docker` however it is still available on the node, but it is not used.

To list the containers use the below command:

```
crictl ps
```

For the complete reference: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md